# SQL Query with group by clause, but counting two distinct values as if they were the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple table with two columns, like the one below:

```
Id | Name
 0 |   A
 1 |   A
 2 |   B
 3 |   B
 4 |   C
 5 |   D
 6 |   E
 7 |   E
```

I want to make a SQL query which will count how many times each "Name" appears on the table. However, I need a few of these values to count as if they were the same. For example, a normal group by query would be:

```
  select Name, count(*)
    from table
group by Name
```

The above query would produce the result:

```
Name | Count
  A  |   2
  B  |   2
  C  |   1
  D  |   1
  E  |   2
```

but I need the query to count "A" and "B" as if they were only "A", and to count "D" and "E" as if they were only "D", so that the result would be like:

```
Name | Count
  A  |   4            // (2 "A"s + 2 "B"s)
  C  |   1
  D  |   3            // (1 "D"  + 2 "E"s)
```

How can I make this kind of query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make translation with `case`. Also, you can use subquery or CTE so you don't have [to repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
with cte as (
    select
        case Name
            when 'B' then 'A'
            when 'E' then 'D'
            else Name
        end as Name
    from table
)
select Name, count(*)
from cte
group by Name
```

or with with online translation table:

```
select
    isnull(R.B, t.Name), count(*)
from table as t
    left outer join (
        select 'A', 'B' union all
        select 'E', 'D'
    ) as R(A, B) on R.A = t.Name
group by isnull(R.B, t.Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need `A` and `B`, `D` and `E`, to count the same, you can build a query like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE Name WHEN 'B' THEN 'A' WHEN 'E' THEN 'D' ELSE Name END as Name
,   COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY CASE Name WHEN 'B' THEN 'A' WHEN 'E' THEN 'D' ELSE Name END
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45c68/3).

Comment: I'd also avoid using 2 cases because of DRY principle - it's harder to modify in the future

Comment: @RomanPekar Unfortunately, SQL Server does not let you group by name: to reuse the expression, I'd need to do a nested query, which would be cleaner from the DRY point of view, but not as readable.

Comment: that's why I like CTE so much :) For me it's equally readable but much more easy to modify. I'd also say that one-liner case is also not very readable (may be subjective thing)

Answer (score 0):

With a layer of abstraction and a `CASE` ([SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96b7c/3)):

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT CASE Name WHEN 'B' THEN 'A'
                     WHEN 'E' THEN 'D'
                     ELSE Name
           END AS Name
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT Name, COUNT(1)
FROM x
GROUP BY Name
```

---

With a translation table ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93104/2)):

```
CREATE TABLE Translate(FromName char(1), ToName char(1));

INSERT INTO Translate VALUES ('B', 'A'), ('E', 'D');

SELECT COALESCE(t.ToName, a.Name) Name, COUNT(1)
FROM Table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Translate t ON a.Name = t.FromName
GROUP BY COALESCE(t.ToName, a.Name)
```

FWIW, you can also do this with a VALUES derived table instead of a real table ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96b7c/2)):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.ToName, a.Name) Name, COUNT(1)
FROM Table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    VALUES ('B', 'A'), 
           ('E', 'D')
) t(FromName, ToName) ON a.Name = t.FromName
GROUP BY COALESCE(t.ToName, a.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
 select t.a,count(t.id) from  (
       select case name when 'A' then 'A' when 'B' then 'A' 
                        when 'C' then 'C' when 'D' then 'C'
                        when 'D' then 'D' when 'E' then 'D' end as A,id
        from test) as t
    group by A;
```